# Pitchipoy Eye Rig Issue

Tags: faces, rigify

I'm having trouble with the pitchipoy face rig where the controls for the eye don't work properly when moving horizontally. The eyes moves on the Y plane and protrude the mesh instead of moving to the right and left.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/lc8gjzl5g5wfoo2/Kisha.blend

Comment: I've had the same problem until i noticed (in front view) that i crossed the bones of the eye center.